# How to use multi Auth in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Does anyone know how to use multi authenticate in laravel 5.2 !
 I want to use It but I don't know how ? 
does anyone has a tutorial or project setting up multi authentication?

Comment: [Here's how to use](http://sarav.co/blog/multiple-authentication-in-laravel/)

Comment: Do you even tried to make a more authentications? The base for authentication is `Auth::attempt` method (read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: @BasheerAhmed  i mean i want to use in laravel 5.2

Comment: That will give you a basic idea of how to start with..

Comment: @GrzegorzGajda i am a newbie in laravel ! i just know how to use default user authentication ! if you have done multi authenticate, can you give me some example project ?

Comment: is laravel 5.2 the same with that page @BasheerAhmed ?

Comment: here i've written the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example/34783443#34783443

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need two tables `users` and `admins`
Run command following command to create built in auth

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Two models Users(Already exist) and Admin

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
 
}
```

Now open config/auth.php and make the following changes

```html
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'admins' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Admin::class,
         ],
    ],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
  'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Create a new Middleware `RedirectIfNotAdmin`

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
 {
  if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
   return redirect('/admin/login');
  }
 
  return $next($request);
 }
}
```

Changes in Kernel.php

```html
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
 ];


protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            //\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],
  
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];


protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
  'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
    ];
```

Create a new folder Http/Controller/Adminauth and copy the files from Http/Controller/Auth folder

Open the file Http/Controller/Adminauth/AuthController.php and make the following changes

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Adminauth;

use App\Admin;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
 protected $guard = 'admin';
 
 public function showLoginForm()
 {
  if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())
  {
   return redirect('/admin');
  }
  
  return view('admin.auth.login');
 }
 
 public function showRegistrationForm()
 {
  return view('admin.auth.register');
 }
 
 public function resetPassword()
 {
  return view('admin.auth.passwords.email');
 }
 
 public function logout(){
  Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
  return redirect('/admin/login');
 }
}
```

Create new folder Http/Controller/admin, copy Controller.php file in the folder from Http/Controller/

create new file Http/Controller/admin/employee.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use Auth;
use App\Admin;

class Employee extends Controller
{
 public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
   }
 
 public function index(){
  return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

move to resources/views create new folder resources/views/admin
copy

`resources/views/auth, resources/views/layouts & resources/views/home.blade.php`

and post into `resources/views/admin` and open the each file in admin folder and add admin before each path, Now the path should look like

`@extends('admin.layouts.app')`

and your Http/routes.php look like

```html
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/admin/login','Adminauth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login','Adminauth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('/admin/password/reset','Adminauth\PasswordController@resetPassword');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/logout','Adminauth\AuthController@logout');
 
    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'Adminauth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'Adminauth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\Employee@index');
});



Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
 
 
});
```

Thats it open your site in browser and check
and for admin yoursiteurl/admin

Enjoy....

Comment: Thanks for this, it was great, one thing I am finding though is that the "/admin/logout" route is being overridden by my "/" route in 'web'. So that it redirects straight to "/" instead of carrying out the work in "/admin/logout". Is there a reason for that behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for great tutorial.
The only problem is that the routes Auth default user are visible although this log with the admin.
Example:
I'm logged in as administrator through the route admins/login, but even I can see the path /login of the default user of Laravel and vice versa.
As I can fix that? Greetings from Chile

Comment: i am getting this error when calling /admin/password/reset        "ErrorException in ResetsPasswords.php line 252: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Adminauth\PasswordController::resetPassword()"

Answer (score 6):

First, we create two models: user and admin

Then, we update the config/auth.php file:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'user',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'App\User',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'App\Admin',
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'user' => [
            'provider' => 'user',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]
    ]
];
```

Now, modify the app/Http/kernel.php file:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class      
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Create `LoginController` and set the following code in it.

Note: You have to create login pages for 'user' as well as 'admin'. You then have to submit login form requests to the appropriate controller function i.e. `userLogin()` or `adminLogin()`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth, Input;
use App\User;
use App\Admin;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function userLogin(){
        $input = Input::all();
        if(count($input) > 0){
            $auth = auth()->guard('user');

            $credentials = [
                'email' =>  $input['email'],
                'password' =>  $input['password'],
            ];

            if ($auth->attempt($credentials)) {
                return redirect()->action('LoginController@profile');
            } else {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        } else {
            return view('user.login');
        }
    }

    public function adminLogin(){
        $input = Input::all();
        if(count($input) > 0){
            $auth = auth()->guard('admin');

            $credentials = [
                'email' =>  $input['email'],
                'password' =>  $input['password'],
            ];

            if ($auth->attempt($credentials)) {
                 return redirect()->action('LoginController@profile');                     
            } else {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        } else {
            return view('admin.login');
        }
    }

    public function profile(){
        if(auth()->guard('admin')->check()){
             pr(auth()->guard('admin')->user()->toArray());
        }         
        if(auth()->guard('user')->check()){
            pr(auth()->guard('user')->user()->toArray());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use multi auth with default AuthController.
can you make me correct. I have implemented and its working fine for user table however its authenticating admin from admin table but not creating session for admin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example

Comment: I am getting error: Authentication user provider [] is not defined.

Comment: `auth()->guard('admin')->user()` returns null

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I just add a field to the user table called usertype and pass appropriate values like 0=admin, 1=user etc.

This approach helps in avoiding the unnecessary headache of creating different user roles or types.

Though this may not sound ideal, but helps in saving lots of time.