# Can I create a new class that inherits from User in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I am pretty new to laravel (using 5.2 which is the latest version to date), therefore I have the following dilemma: I know that Laravel comes with a `User` class right out of the box, but I want to develop a system where I can have another two types of users called `Researcher` and `Admin`.

My main need to create completely different classes of users (Researcher and Admin), possibly inheriting from `User` because the business logic is almost 100% different amongst them and I would not want to create a column in the database to classify the type of user. Furthermore, there aren't many fields that overlap between the stock `User`, `Admin` and `Researcher` classes.

My main question would be: Will everything still work the same (Auth Controller, middleware enabled, etc...) if I inherit from `User` for my other 2 classes? I know the principles of OOP and by intuition I assume I should be fine if I do the following:

```
//'Stock' User class:
//
class User extends Authenticatable{
    //Any overlapping logic between Researcher and Admin.
}


class Researcher extends User{
    //My class definition here.
}

class Admin extends User{
    //My class definition here.
}
```

And then use both classes as I would normally use an instance of the class `User`. By that, I mean use all the methods and right out of the box `User` functionality.

QUESTION EXTENSION:
While writing my question, I realize that the class `User` looks like so by default:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Could not I just do the following instead of inheriting from `User` to create my other 2 classes (`Researcher` & `Admin`):

```
//Researcher Class:
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Researcher extends Authenticatable
{
    //Class definition...
}

...

//Admin Class:
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    //Class definition
}
```

In this approach, I am trying to 'mimic' the `User` class. The thing is that I don't know if there is any logic in the Kernel that is hardcoded and is being referenced to the `User` class implicitly.

Any thought and help will be much appreciated. Sorry if this is silly to you. I am just getting started with the laravel framework.

Cheers!

Comment: If what you are looking to have multiple classes for a user to be authenticated, then read the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490600/how-to-use-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-2 I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can extend the class `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Researcher extends Authenticatable {
    //My class definition here.
}
```

If you take a look at `User` class:

```
class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

you see that it extends the `Model` class and implements all the other useful interfaces for authentication handling

**you can safely extend the `User` class, because Laravel is good enough to work with the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface to handle the authentication** and not directly with the `User` class

In fact if you check in:

```
Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php
```

That is the main class for auth handling, you'll see that all the auth actions are made against the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface, i.e:

```
/**
 * Log a user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  bool  $remember
 * @return void
 */
public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
{
    //other code
}
```

I Think that your real problem would be: how to instantiate the classes `Researcher` and `Admin` instead of the `User` class during the authentication process?

If you use Eloquent as authentication driver, by default Laravel is going to use the `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` to create an instance of the Model. So, if you want to create an instance one of your classes instead of `User`, you should override this provider (or create one of your own) and here you could choose which class to instantiate

Comment: I think the best here is to go with your approach. The only thing I would like to know is where would I register that new provider? I am assuming under `App\config\app.php` am I right? My first thought was to create both under `Illuminate\Auth\` as `EloquentAdminProvider` and `EloquentResearcherProvider`, but then it does not make much sense since it is not part of the Illuminate's package. I think I'll create both providers under a 'custom' directory `App\Custom\Providers\`.

Comment: @JackGal :  you can create a custom service provider in wich you can register the new `EloquentResearcherProvider`.  and make the app use it instead of the default `EloquentUserProvider`. You should never write your code under the `vendor` folder

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to work with this concept is with roles and keeping the User Class intact. See https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission for details.