# Laravel - Extending User model

Tags: laravel

I have a class `Seller` that `extends` laravel's `User` model 
as the following

```
namespace App; 
class Seller extends User{
   public function products(){
       return $this->hasMany(Products::class);
   }
}
```

in the `ModelFactory.php` I have the following code

```
$factory->define(Transaction::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
  $seller = Seller::has('products')->get()->random();
  $buyer = User::all()->except($seller->id)->random();
  return [
    'quantity' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 3),
    'buyer_id' => $buyer->id,
    'product_id' => $seller->products->random()->id
 ];
});
```

I'm getting the following error

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tutorial.sellers' doesn't
>   exist (SQL: select * from `sellers` where exists (select * from
>   `products` where `sellers`.`id` = `products`.`seller_id`))

the `Product` class is as the following

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model{
     const AVAILABLE_PRODUCT = 'available';
     const UNAVAILABLE_PRODUCT = 'unavailable';

     protected $fillable = [
         'name',
         'description',
         'quantity',
         'status',
         'image',
         'seller_id'
     ];

     public function isAvailable(){

         return $this->status == Product::AVAILABLE_PRODUCT;

     }

    public function seller(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Seller::class);

    }

    public function categories(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);

    }

    public function transactions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }

}
```

apparently, the generated query does not take the inheritance into consideration. 
I tried changing `$seller = Seller::has('products')->get()->random();` into `$seller = User::has('products')->get()->random();`
but then the line `'product_id' => $seller->products->random()->id` causes an error since the `products()` method is defined in `seller` class 
What's the best way to do this?

Is it a right way to extend User class ?

I have searched for ways to extend the `User` class.
I found this question: [Model Inheritance in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653415/can-i-create-a-new-class-that-inherits-from-user-in-laravel-5-2)
 didn't help me though.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.36, PHP 7.1.11

Comment: unless otherwise specified Eloquent uses the Classname snake-cased and plural as the table name.   https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Add `protected $table = 'users';` in your `Seller` class.

Comment: @Marwelln Thanks,, the above mentioned error is gone now but I'm getting this error now `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::random()` 
Not sure which `random` it's referencing

Comment: The `random()` it's referencing is this one:  `$seller->products->random()->id`. Just make it `$seller->products()->get()->random()->id`. You might also be able to use `$seller->products->inRandomOrder()->first()->id` but I can't test that right now, should work though.

Comment: Add `protected $table = 'users';` in your `User::class`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize:

Laravel will use the `Class Name` as the table name if not explicitly declared on the model. This causes Laravel to automatically assume `sellers` as the table name in the query. To resolve this add the following to the extending Model:

```
protected $table = 'users'
```

Finally, you're attempting to use `->random()` on a query builder instance, but that's not what you want. You want to use it on the collection. You can do any of the following:

```
$seller->products()->get()->random()->id;
```

The above will perform the query and retrieve all products, then get you a random item from the returned collection, then retrieve the ID. The better (more efficient) way, is to let the Query builder handle it:

```
$seller->products->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
```

Comment: This is very helpful for having multiple user classes with different relationships on them that both extend the User class, e.g. Employee and Customer classes.

Comment: @plushyObject Actually in most cases you'll resolve it using a hierachy; the "user" entity will contain the common fields between all user types.

Comment: @ncastro what do you mean a hierarchy?

Comment: @plushyObject Sorry I was trying to support your comment, which is correct. Employee (is a) user, Customer (is a) user; i.e. both have username and password. Even some ORMs require a discriminator field (in the User entity) to resolve the composition of the child Object.