# laravel 5.2 multi auth not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to use laravel 5.2 multi auth but not working. I created 2 guards, 
`admin` and `mhs`. but I can't login with `mhs` guard. When I tried to login with mhs guard, it's always redirect to that login form. And I tried following this [How to use multi Auth in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490600/how-to-use-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-2/34883723#34883723)

this is my `auth.php`

**Guards**

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],      

     'mhs' =>  [
    'driver'   => 'session',
    'provider' => 'mhs',
],
```

**Provider**

```
'providers' => [

'admin' =>  [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model'  => App\User::class,
],

'mhs' =>  [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model'  => App\Mahasiswa::class,
],
],
```

This is my `routes.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {      
Route::get('admin/login', 'LoginController@admingetLogin');
Route::post('admin/login', 'LoginController@adminLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@getLogout');

Route::get('mhs/login', 'LoginController@mhsgetLogin');
Route::post('mhs/login', 'LoginController@mhsLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@getLogout');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('/home', 'MahasiswaController@index');
Route::get('/mhs', 'MahasiswaController@mhs');
Route::resource('mahasiswa', 'MahasiswaController');
});
```

and this is my `LoginController`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Mahasiswa;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


protected $username = 'username';

public function admingetLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');

}
public function mhsgetLogin()
{
    return view('mahasiswa.login');

}
public function adminLogin(){
    $input = Input::all();
    if(count($input) > 0){
        $auth = auth()->guard('admin');

        $credentials = [
            'username' =>  $input['username'],
            'password' =>  $input['password'],
        ];

        if ($auth->attempt($credentials)) {
            if(auth()->guard('admin')->check()){
         auth()->guard('admin')->user()->toArray();
         return redirect()->intended('/');
     }
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}


public function mhsLogin(){
    $input = Input::all();
    if(count($input) > 0){
        $auth = auth()->guard('mhs');

        $credentials = [
            'username' =>  $input['username'],
            'password' =>  $input['password'],
        ];

        if ($auth->attempt($credentials)) {
            if(auth()->guard('mhs')->check()){
         auth()->guard('mhs')->user()->toArray();
         return redirect()->intended('/mhs');   
         }                
        } else {
            echo 'Error';
        }
    } else {
        return view('mhs.login');
    }
}

public function profile(){
    if(auth()->guard('admin')->check()){
         pr(auth()->guard('admin')->user()->toArray());
         return redirect()->intended('/');
    }         
    if(auth()->guard('mhs')->check()){
        pr(auth()->guard('mhs')->user()->toArray());
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    } 
}
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
}
```

I'm stuck to this in 4 days, Can anyone help me?
It would be very helpful if someone could resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your guards and providers looks good.
First, check your `auth` in one guard. Maybe you have problem with `attempt`.
Use `Auth::attempt` for default guard. You can check result of this in

```
 public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
```

This is in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php`

Maybe is problem with checking password

Comment: what I have to do when I open `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php` ? sorry I still dont understand

Comment: Dump attempt function . Its return true or false?