# Laravel Authentication with 2 types of users

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best approach to this problem, I'm making a web-app that is to have two types of users.
- Administrator (administrators_table)
- User (users_table)

The User has many many more properties than an Administrator which is relatively straight-forward. So we've separated them to different tables.

Ideally, I'd like them to use the same login form. Would my current scenario of two separate tables be recommended, or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: A further thought, would it be ideal to make the users part of the same database table, and separate the 'User details' stuff to a linked table?

Comment: You need to try multiple authentications: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772716/5503275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone's input. Although very good, it was a bit complex for this simple app.

We decided to merge the Admin and Users table, and have an isAdmin column and using Laravel's Middleware to separate the two roles.