# TokenMismatchException for API in Laravel 5.2.31

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**What Am I trying?**

I already have a website and I am trying Token based authentication for an API in same code and below is the start for sample authentication code

**I created a controller below is the code.**

```
class AccountController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function apilogin($UserData) {
        return json_decode($UserData);
    }
}
```

**My route config is below.**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth.api'], function () {
    Route::post('/apilogin', 'API\User\Account\AccountController@apilogin');
});
```

**Then from the Postman Chrome Extension, I have posted the request and worked fine if I comment the following line from $middlewareGroups in Kernel.php

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

I have no issues VerifyCsrfToken if I do GET request from POSTMan Extension

Comment: did you set anything in config/auth.php if yes than show ?

Comment: I did not mention `, 'middleware' => 'auth:api'` in Route group because I am assuming that this route should be accessible to all and should not be protected. I am sending post request of UserName and Password to get api_token. Is that fine?

Answer (score 9):

Open your `app\http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

Here edit `$except` property with:

```
protected $except = [
  'api/*' 
];
```

This will exclude your api routes from CSRF verification.

Comment: Its working perfect for me. @pankaj , please mark this green If Its working for you. because It is a correct answer.

Comment: Is it secure? @Abhishek

Comment: Yup but you should use some token for API requests. So that your APIs don't get abused by any insane person.

Comment: how does disabling CSRF verification make it secure?

Comment: @Abhishek u said yup. so it is secure. that's why I asked why.

Comment: @Capt.Teemo Can you please read the full comment? "Yup but you should use some token for API requests. So that your APIs don't get abused by any insane person."

Comment: @Abhishek you said yup it is secure. I'm asking why is it secure. you should have said no if you mean that we should still use token.

Answer (score 0):

In your route.php set below code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => API_PREFIX,'middleware' => 'auth.api'], function() 
{
 // Your Route
}
```

In your kernal.php set below middleware, it is good to use a diffrent middleware for api.

```
'auth.api' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthenticate::class,
```

Add new **middleware** ApiAuthenticate.php

```
class ApiAuthenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'api')
    {
        if (\Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response("Invalid user");
        }
        else {
            return $next($request);  
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Check your get and post methods too

Comment: I updated the question. Please check. I am still facing same issue.

Comment: If I do authentication from my web page, it works perfectly.Now issue is in Token based API authentication.

Comment: did you get something in your middleware?  i am accepting that you can't get UserName ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you explain more about your query?

Comment: for debugging when you print_r(Input::all()) in ApiAuthenticate did you get something;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112643/discussion-between-helper-and-dsraj).

Comment: I did a change and your solution is good if I use GET verb. If I use POST. I get `TokenMismatchException`.

Comment: ohhh, its something new for me also
Updated in answer :)

Comment: What exactly was changed by you for POST method?

Comment: use can use Route::any() for get and post both request

Comment: Can u tell me why POST request `Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth.api'], function () {
    Route::post('/apilogin', 'API\User\Account\AccountController@apilogin');
});` works if I comment the line `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` ? I also mentioned the same thing in my original post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413887/laravel-5-2-need-an-example-which-implements-default-authentication-drivers-m/34416305#34416305

Answer (score 0):

TokenMismatchException  generally occurs when csrf token not present in form or expired csrf token or tamperd csrf token.

First:

Make sure you added in form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Or

Clear try with clear cache for view files

Or

Check if any redirection are there in flow

Finally if everything fails if you want to customize this error . You can handle this error in hanlers. check `[this][1]`

Comment: This is about API. If you see my Controller action method, it returns JSON data for the post request.

Comment: As far as my knowledge tokenmismtach error will occur only on request call. It's not related to what it return.

Comment: I am posting the data from Postman Chrome Extension. I am doing this because I am working on Android to interact with Laravel for API purpose.

Comment: Oh just try remove auth middleware for login and register. for these two you don't have authorization tokens.