# creating Multiple Authentication Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, authentication

I plan to develop a system that has three two types (admin, users). I want to have each user types information stored in a separate table for easy access and to reduce the number of blank fields (if they were all in one table).

i need all users login in the same login form not separated form for each one of them

Comment: You need to use permissions. Read about Authorization in Laravel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34416305/5503275

Comment: I already read about it but the issue is how to do all users login in the same login form